# int overflow error in ctypes array pointer

Tags: python, c++, pointers, dll, ctypes

So I am trying to use ctypes to use the functions defined in a .dll file for controlling a camera. I have something like this:

```
import ctypes as C
import numpy as np

memoryid = C.c_int()
memoryaddress = C.c_char_p()
img = np.zeros((dy,dx),dtype=np.uint8)
uc480.is_CopyImageMem(handle,memoryaddress,memoryid,img.ctypes.data)
```

Sometimes I get an error `ArgumentError: argument 4: <class 'OverflowError'>: int too long to convert` for the last line. But this depends on the computer. Sometimes this errer doesn't pop up and everything seems to work. (but I have just tried three different computers, two have errors, one doesn't, so I can't draw much conclusion from it.)

From the documentation (https://www.thorlabs.com/software/THO/ThorCam/Programming/ITN000563-D02.pdf p.159), the fourth argument of the last function should be a pointer to the destination memory to copy the image to. Does it mean that the fourth argument is too long for Python to handle? When I tried to `print(img.ctypes.data)`, I get something like `2813806678080`. Is this causing the problem? Any ideas how I should solve this?

Comment: How exactly is this question related to c++?

Comment: Perhaps your last argument should be `img.ctypes.data_as(C.POINTER(C.c_uint8))`. You should also set the function's `argtypes`. Do you not also need to give a non-zero value for `memoryid`? The docs imply you do, but it's not clear to me.

Comment: @101 It does seem to work (at least no Exception). Can you briefly tell me the difference between the two? When I read the numpy documentation, both seem to give a pointer.

Comment: I suspect it's because a Python integer is of arbitrary length, which may be too long (overflow error) or even get truncated. I'd guess that's why it works on some PCs and not others, does the PC that doesn't work have a different bit architecture? In general with ctypes you want to be settings `argtpyes` to enforce type checking and avoid these sort of errors.

Comment: Set the `argtypes` (and `restype`) for `uc480.is_CopyImageMem`, otherwise they will be treated as 32bit integers!